# XSLT comparison of existing and new xml

Tags: xslt, comparison

I am trying to compare two xml nodes but right now deep-equal function of XSLT returns me false even that two xml nodes are directly same.

I have two variables one contains new calculated value($key-data-val):

```
<translation-key key="00016403"><textinfo SPRAS="E" MAKTX="Heater-defrost"/></translation-key>
```

The other is existing one($existing-asset) :

```
<asset id="104606" version="21" currversion="0" content_version="1" id_extern="bsh:cmd.temp-keyset.00016403" name="csmatke y-00016403" type="temp." application="default" state="0" deletion="0" modified_by="361" domain="root." domain2="root." modified_date="2017-02-28T13:10:27Z" non_owner_access="2" iscancellation="0" has_master_file="0" has_update_geometry="0" storage_state="0" created_by="361" creation_date="2017-02-28T11:10:55Z" rowid="AAAFBCAAFAAAUkuAAd" usn="0" tcn="60" ccn="61">
   <asset_feature sid="1665764" asset_id="104606" asset_currversion="0" feature="bsh:cmd.importer-type" isversioned="0" timestamp="2017-02-28T13:10:27Z" party="361" value_string="csmatkeys" rowid="AAAFFNAAFAAARmzABU" />
   <asset_feature sid="1665763" asset_id="104606" asset_version="21" feature="bsh:cmd.processing-status" isversioned="1" timestamp="2017-02-28T13:10:27Z" party="361" value_key="todo" rowid="AAAFFNAAFAAARmzAA/" />
   <asset_feature sid="1665765" asset_id="104606" asset_currversion="0" feature="bsh:cmd.record" isversioned="0" timestamp="2017-02-28T13:10:27Z" party="361" rowid="AAAFFNAAFAAARmNAAg">
      <xmldata>
         <translation-key key="00016403">
            <textinfo SPRAS="E" MAKTX="Heater-defrost" />
         </translation-key>
      </xmldata>
   </asset_feature>
   <asset_feature sid="1665760" asset_id="104606" asset_version="21" feature="censhare:owner" isversioned="1" timestamp="2017-02-28T11:10:55Z" party="361" value_long="2" rowid="AAAFFNAAFAAARmzAA9" />
   <asset_feature sid="1665761" asset_id="104606" asset_version="21" feature="censhare:owner" isversioned="1" timestamp="2017-02-28T11:10:55Z" party="361" value_long="361" rowid="AAAFFNAAFAAARmzAA+" />
   <asset_feature sid="1665762" asset_id="104606" asset_version="21" feature="censhare:uuid" isversioned="1" timestamp="2017-02-28T11:10:55Z" party="361" value_string="931a4670-fda6-11e6-b375-06002d8a858f" rowid="AAAFFNAAFAAARmzAA8" />
</asset>
```

So i am simply trying to compare if contents of translation-keys are different or same, if they are different i will overwrite a new content into that asset.

So what i am trying to compare the two nodes of translation-key:

```
<xsl:message>Comparison check : <xsl:value-of select="deep-equal($existing-asset//translation-key,$keydata-val)"/></xsl:message>
```

This returns as false, and i want to check if  element content is changed or not, there might be added text info or deleted text info or the content inside textinfo's attributes could be changed, any of these cases should return me as false.

But right now deep-equal directly returns me false...

Can anyone help me how i can get this goal to compare two nodes like deepequal function ?

Comment: Please show minimal but complete XSLT samples allowing us to reproduce the problem. It is crucial to show how exactly the variables are defined to be able to tell why `deep-equal` fails.

Comment: From my point, i should implement another thing to compare them, because strange thing is that when i tried that directly on xslt variables without calculation, "deep-equal" doesn't fail.

Comment: Show us your XSLT code setting up the variables, then we can tell more. If one is a document and you then compare the document to the element selected by `$existing-asset//translation-key` the comparison will fail.